# Interpreting Output from sess.run in tensorflow

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow, recommendation-engine

I have two chunks of code below that come from the repo https://github.com/kang205/DVBPR.  This is a python implementation of the paper:

Visually-Aware Fashion Recommendation and Design with Generative Image Models

I’m trying to run it, understand it, and adapt it.  As I understand it in the paper they first train a siamese cnn network (DVBPR main.py code) to be a preference predictor.  Then there’s a gan network trained to generate images similar to the images the customer likes, and finally the preference maximization piece (pm main.py) that runs a regularization process to keep the matrix factorization model using the preference predictor from being overfit.

I’m trying to skip the gan part and just get preference scores for a new image from the siamese network I trained previously.  That’s what I’m trying to do in the “prefrence code” chunk below.  I’m loading back in the checkpoint weights from the trained siamese network, declaring some variables, and finally passing the session a user, an image they haven’t seen and idx.

I don’t exactly understand what idx is doing or it’s purpose.  If anyone can explain that I’d be grateful.

Also I’m trying to understand what is being returned in the output when I print the sess.run.  Is it the image tensor from the image I passed sess.run and the preference score?  I notice if I change the order in the brackets in sess.run it changes the order of the output.  So array([ 99.19335938], dtype=float32) follows from idx.

I’m very new to tensorFlow so all tips are greatly appreciated.

Siamese network code (DVBPR main.py):

```
import sys
import math
import random
import time
from PIL import Image
import Queue
import numpy as np
import threading
from cStringIO import StringIO
import tensorflow as tf

dataset_name = 'AmazonFashion6ImgPartitioned.npy'

#Hyper-prameters
K = 100 # Latent dimensionality
lambda1 = 0.001 # Weight decay
lambda2 = 1.0 # Regularizer for theta_u
learning_rate = 1e-4
training_epoch = 20
batch_size = 128
dropout = 0.5 # Dropout, probability to keep units
numldprocess=4 # multi-threading for loading images


dataset = np.load('../'+dataset_name)

[user_train, user_validation, user_test, Item, usernum, itemnum] = dataset

# Create some wrappers for simplicity
def conv2d(x, W, b, strides=1):
    # Conv2D wrapper, with bias and relu activation
    x = tf.nn.conv2d(x, W, strides=[1, strides, strides, 1], padding='SAME')
    x = tf.nn.bias_add(x, b)
    return tf.nn.relu(x)

def maxpool2d(x, k=2):
    return tf.nn.max_pool(x, ksize=[1, k, k, 1], strides=[1, k, k, 1],
                          padding='SAME')

def avgpool2d(x, k=2):
    return tf.nn.avg_pool(x, ksize=[1, k, k, 1], strides=[1, k, k, 1],
                          padding='SAME')

weights = {
    'wc1': [11, 11, 3, 64],
    'wc2': [5, 5, 64, 256],
    'wc3': [3, 3, 256, 256],
    'wc4': [3, 3, 256, 256],
    'wc5': [3, 3, 256, 256],    
    'wd1': [7*7*256, 4096],
    'wd2': [4096, 4096],
    'wd3': [4096, K],
}

biases = {
    'bc1': [64],
    'bc2': [256],
    'bc3': [256],
    'bc4': [256],
    'bc5': [256],
    'bd1': [4096],
    'bd2': [4096],
    'bd3': [K],
}

def Weights(name):
    return tf.get_variable(name,dtype=tf.float32,shape=weights[name],initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer())

def Biases(name):
    return tf.get_variable(name,dtype=tf.float32,initializer=tf.zeros(biases[name]))

# Create CNN model
def CNN(x,dropout):
    # Reshape input picture
    x = tf.reshape(x, shape=[-1, 224, 224, 3])


    conv1 = conv2d(x, Weights('wc1'), Biases('bc1'), strides=4)
    conv1 = tf.nn.relu(conv1)
    conv1 = maxpool2d(conv1, k=2)

    conv2 = conv2d(conv1, Weights('wc2'), Biases('bc2'))
    conv2 = tf.nn.relu(conv2)
    conv2 = maxpool2d(conv2, k=2)

    conv3 = conv2d(conv2, Weights('wc3'), Biases('bc3'))
    conv3 = tf.nn.relu(conv3)

    conv4 = conv2d(conv3, Weights('wc4'), Biases('bc4'))
    conv4 = tf.nn.relu(conv4)

    conv5 = conv2d(conv4, Weights('wc5'), Biases('bc5'))
    conv5 = tf.nn.relu(conv5)
    conv5 = maxpool2d(conv5, k=2)

    fc1 = tf.reshape(conv5, [-1,weights['wd1'][0]])
    fc1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(fc1, Weights('wd1')), Biases('bd1'))
    fc1 = tf.nn.relu(fc1)
    fc1 = tf.nn.dropout(fc1, dropout)

    fc2 = tf.add(tf.matmul(fc1, Weights('wd2')), Biases('bd2'))
    fc2 = tf.nn.relu(fc2)
    fc2 = tf.nn.dropout(fc2, dropout)

    fc3 = tf.add(tf.matmul(fc2, Weights('wd3')), Biases('bd3'))

    return fc3



    image1=(tf.to_float(image1)-127.5)/127.5
    image2=(tf.to_float(image2)-127.5)/127.5
    _image_test=(tf.to_float(image_test)-127.5)/127.5

    u=tf.reshape(u,shape=[batch_size])
    i=tf.reshape(i,shape=[batch_size])
    j=tf.reshape(j,shape=[batch_size])

    keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32) #dropout (keep probability)

    #siamese networks
    with tf.variable_scope("DVBPR") as scope:
        result1 = CNN(image1,dropout)
        scope.reuse_variables()
        result2 = CNN(image2,dropout)
        result_test = CNN(_image_test,1.0)
        nn_regularizers = sum(map(tf.nn.l2_loss,[Weights('wd1'), Weights('wd2'), Weights('wd3'), Weights('wc1'), Weights('wc2'), Weights('wc3'), Weights('wc4'), Weights('wc5')]))
        thetau = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([usernum,K],minval=0,maxval=1)/100)

    cost_train = tf.reduce_sum(tf.log(tf.sigmoid(tf.reduce_sum(tf.multiply(tf.gather(thetau,u),tf.subtract(result1,result2)),1,keep_dims=True))))
    regularizers = tf.nn.l2_loss(tf.gather(thetau,u))
    cost_train -= lambda1 * nn_regularizers + lambda2 * regularizers
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate).minimize(-cost_train)    

# Initializing the variables
init = tf.initialize_all_variables()

def AUC(train,test,U,I):
    ans=0
    cc=0
    for u in train:    
        i=test[u][0]['productid']
        T=np.dot(U[u,:],I.T)
        cc+=1
        M=set()      
        for item in train[u]:
            M.add(item['productid'])
        M.add(i)

        count=0
        tmpans=0
        #for j in xrange(itemnum):
        for j in random.sample(xrange(itemnum),100): #sample
            if j in M: continue
            if T[i]>T[j]: tmpans+=1
            count+=1
        tmpans/=float(count)
        ans+=tmpans
    ans/=float(cc)
    return ans

def Evaluation(step):
    print '...'
    U=sess.run(thetau)
    I=np.zeros([itemnum,K],dtype=np.float32)
    idx=np.array_split(range(itemnum),(itemnum+batch_size-1)/batch_size)

    input_images=np.zeros([batch_size,224,224,3],dtype=np.int8)
    for i in range(len(idx)):
        cc=0
        for j in idx[i]:
            input_images[cc]=np.uint8(np.asarray(Image.open(StringIO(Item[j]['imgs'])).convert('RGB').resize((224,224))))
            cc+=1
        I[idx[i][0]:(idx[i][-1]+1)]=sess.run(result_test,feed_dict={image_test:input_images})[:(idx[i][-1]-idx[i][0]+1)]
    print 'export finised!'
    np.save('UI_'+str(K)+'_'+str(step)+'.npy',[U,I])
    return AUC(user_train,user_validation,U,I), AUC(user_train,user_test,U,I)

def sample(user):
    u = random.randrange(usernum)
    numu = len(user[u])
    i = user[u][random.randrange(numu)]['productid']
    M=set()
    for item in user[u]:
        M.add(item['productid'])
    while True:
        j=random.randrange(itemnum)
        if (not j in M): break
    return (u,i,j)

def load_image_async():
    while True:
        (uuu,iii,jjj)=sample(user_train)
        jpg1=np.uint8(np.asarray(Image.open(StringIO(Item[iii]['imgs'])).convert('RGB').resize((224,224))))
        jpg2=np.uint8(np.asarray(Image.open(StringIO(Item[jjj]['imgs'])).convert('RGB').resize((224,224))))
        sess.run(batch_train_queue_op,feed_dict={queueu:np.asarray([uuu]),
                                                 queuei:np.asarray([iii]),
                                                 queuej:np.asarray([jjj]),
                                                 queueimage1:jpg1,queueimage2:jpg2,
                                                })

f=open('DVBPR.log','w')
config = tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=False,allow_soft_placement=True)
sess=tf.Session(config=config)
sess.run(init)

t=[0]*numldprocess
for i in range(numldprocess):
    t[i] = threading.Thread(target=load_image_async)
    t[i].daemon=True
    t[i].start()

oneiteration = 0
for item in user_train: oneiteration+=len(user_train[item])

step = 1
saver = tf.train.Saver([k for k in tf.global_variables() if k.name.startswith('DVBPR')])

epoch=0
while step * batch_size <= training_epoch*oneiteration+1:

    sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={keep_prob: dropout})

    print 'Step#'+str(step)+' CNN update'

    if step*batch_size / oneiteration >epoch:
        epoch+=1
        saver.save(sess,'./DVBPR_auc_'+str(K)+'_'+str(step)+'.ckpt')
        auc_valid,auc_test=Evaluation(step)
        print 'Epoch #'+str(epoch)+':'+str(auc_test)+' '+str(auc_valid)+'\n'
        f.write('Epoch #'+str(epoch)+':'+str(auc_test)+' '+str(auc_valid)+'\n')
        f.flush()

    step += 1
print "Optimization Finished!"
```

Code for preference score (pm main.py):

```
from cStringIO import StringIO
def loadimg(item):
    return np.round(np.array(Image.open(StringIO(Item[item]['imgs'])).convert('RGB').resize((224,224)),dtype=np.float64))

with tf.device('/cpu:0'):

    # creating placeholder variable
    # _image_test has form <tf.Tensor 'div_4:0' shape=(64, 224, 224, 3) dtype=float32>
    image_test=tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.uint8,shape=[64,224,224,3])
    _image_test=(tf.to_float(image_test)-127.5)/127.5

    keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32) #dropout (keep probability)

    # sharing variable by capturing scope and setting reuse
    with tf.variable_scope("DVBPR") as scope:

        # creating model from input image and drop out, returns tensor shape (100,1)
        result_test = CNN(_image_test,1.0)

        # creating variable thetau which is tensor of shape [usernum,D] filled with random values in range 0 to 1
        thetau = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([usernum,D],minval=0,maxval=1)/100)


# Initializing the variables
init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
config = tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=False,allow_soft_placement=True)
config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True


# creating session
sess=tf.Session(config=config)


sess.run(init)


# creates object to save all variables in
saver = tf.train.Saver([k for k in tf.global_variables() if k.name.startswith('DVBPR')])

# restore model weights from DVBPR check point
saver.restore(sess,DVBPR_ckpt_path)


# creating tensor for image with same shape as gan_image

tstImg3=np.round(np.array(Image.open(StringIO(Item[119]['imgs'])).convert('RGB').resize((224,224)),dtype=np.float32))

rep_gan=tf.reshape(tstImg3, shape=[-1, 224, 224, 3])


# Note: don't have gpu switch to cpu
with tf.device('/cpu:0'):

    # need to figure out how to substitute image of product customer hasn't seen for get_gen

    gan_image=rep_gan

    # shaping image tensor from gan_image
    image=tf.image.resize_nearest_neighbor(images=gan_image, size=[224,224], align_corners=None, name=None)

    with tf.variable_scope("DVBPR") as scope:
        scope.reuse_variables()

        # running model defined previously to get tensor from "image" variable above
        result = CNN(image,1.0)

_user=12 

# idx and user defined in opt section
user=tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.int32,shape=[1])
idx=tf.reduce_sum(tf.matmul(result,tf.transpose(tf.gather(thetau,user))),1)
# Note: I'm not sure what the purpose of idx is

# run piece from Preference Score with DVBPR instead of opt

print(sess.run([gan_image,idx],feed_dict={user:[_user]}))
# the results below appear to return an image tensor and a preference score


Output:

[array([[[[ 255.,  255.,  255.],
         [ 255.,  255.,  255.],
         [ 255.,  255.,  255.],
         ..., 
         [ 255.,  255.,  255.],
         [ 255.,  255.,  255.],
         [ 255.,  255.,  255.]],

        [[ 255.,  255.,  255.],
         [ 255.,  255.,  255.],
         [ 255.,  255.,  255.],
         ..., 
         [ 255.,  255.,  255.],
         [ 255.,  255.,  255.],
         [ 255.,  255.,  255.]],

        [[ 255.,  255.,  255.],
         [ 255.,  255.,  255.],
         [ 255.,  255.,  255.],
         ..., 
         [ 255.,  255.,  255.],
         [ 255.,  255.,  255.],
         [ 255.,  255.,  255.]],

        ..., 
        [[ 255.,  255.,  255.],
         [ 255.,  255.,  255.],
         [ 255.,  255.,  255.],
         ..., 
         [ 255.,  255.,  255.],
         [ 255.,  255.,  255.],
         [ 255.,  255.,  255.]],

        [[ 255.,  255.,  255.],
         [ 255.,  255.,  255.],
         [ 255.,  255.,  255.],
         ..., 
         [ 255.,  255.,  255.],
         [ 255.,  255.,  255.],
         [ 255.,  255.,  255.]],

        [[ 255.,  255.,  255.],
         [ 255.,  255.,  255.],
         [ 255.,  255.,  255.],
         ..., 
         [ 255.,  255.,  255.],
         [ 255.,  255.,  255.],
         [ 255.,  255.,  255.]]]], dtype=float32), array([ 99.19335938], dtype=float32)]
```